# Infer type from object value

Tags: typescript, zod

I'm trying to have a simple type inference with zod objects for validation, basically I have web socket commands split into different files and I want to validate the input. I created a type to declare them as an object

```
export type EventObject<T> = {
    name: string;
    inputSchema: T;
    callback(input: T): any;
};
```

However when declaring the object I have to pass the generic value, which isn't a problem because I can just do this

```
const schema = z.object({});

export default {
    name: "create",
    inputSchema: schema,
    callback(args) {}
} as EventObject<typeof schema>;
```

However, when I do this and provide another schema which is not what is expected I get no error.

```
const schema = z.object({});
const schema2 = z.object({ test: z.string() });

export default {
    name: "create",
    inputSchema: schema2,
    callback(args) {}
} as EventObject<typeof schema>; // Should have errored because the type of the value in 
// inputSchema doesn't match the type provided as generic
```

How should I transform my type to address this? I'm horrible at doing any type stuff because I mostly consume typescript, I rarely ever write custom types.

Comment: Create an intermediate variable or use `satisfies`: https://tsplay.dev/wXrKDm Note that with `satisfies`, the exported type will not be `EventObject<typeof schema>`.

Comment: I totally forgot that when the schema is empty the types are basically useless because we don't expect any input anyway, thanks for the snippet, works like a charm. Although would you mind if you'd post this as an answer? So I can accept it and if in the future people will have a similar problem they'd know this question is answered.

Comment: Shouldn't `inputSchema` be `z.Schema<T>`, or `input` be `z.infer<T>`,  or something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an intermediate variable before exporting it to check the assignment:

```
const object: EventObject<typeof schema> = {
    name: "create",
    inputSchema: schema2, // error
    callback(args) {}
};

export default object;
```

You can also use the `satisfies` keyword...

```
export default {
    name: "create",
    inputSchema: schema2,
    callback(args) {}
} satisfies EventObject<typeof schema>;
```

but now the imported type does not show up as `EventObject<typeof schema>`:

```
import thing from "./somewhere.js";

thing // { name: string; inputSchema: ... }, NOT EventObject<typeof schema>
```

Of course, this only works if `schema` is not an empty schema, since almost anything is assignable to the empty object type (`z.Schema` is covariant):

```
const schema = z.object({ foo: z.string() }); // THIS CANNOT BE EMPTY
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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)